# Buttons not showing up in jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

I have a transaction edit jQuery dialog that pops up just fine when the correct button is clicked but the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons defined inside the dialog do not show up. The HTML for the dialog is:

```
      <div id="trxpop">
        <div>
            <label for="txtItem1">Item1: </label>
            <input id="txtItem1" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="item1">Item2: </label>      
            <input id="txtItem2" type="text" /><br />
        </div>
  </div>
```

and the jQuery is here

```
jQuery.fn.EditTrx = function (item1, item2) {
$("#txtItem1").val(item1);
$("#item1").val(item1);
$("#trxpop").dialog({
    title: 'Edit Transaction',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Save': function () {
            /* Do stuff */
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    stack: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    zIndex: 1320,
    width: 500
});
```

}

This should work according to all the docs I have read.

Comment: The code for your modal works fine for me.

Comment: That is just odd - for me the dialog shows up without the buttons

Comment: In case my answer does show the buttons for you correctly, do you mind  providing a link to your work or create a fiddle to reproduce the error using your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a new set of brackets around the complete button definition and now it works fine. I edited my original code example above to reflect this change. Thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/G4F7M/

Just works fine for me. Just changed the func call and added a button for opening the dialog:

```
$('input').click(function(){
EditTrx();
});
```

So if those buttons are not displaying it might be something else causing the problem like css.

Comment: I am only showing the function itself - not the function call from the button that opens the dialog. That is workiong just fine and the dialog is opening just fine - it's just that the buttons inside the dialog are not showing up - thanks for the reply though.

Comment: So you can see the buttons inside the fiddle, yea? Not on your page tho?

Comment: Correct - uv - but I have fixed my issue - see below

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists as specified in the accepted answer so, it can be solved by doing the following in your open event of the dialogue control.

```
open: function (event, ui) {
    //For displaying the buttons of GUI.
    $('.ui-button-text').each(function (i) {
        $(this).html($(this).parent().attr('text'));
    })
},
```